# I2C - RS232 controller

Tags: embedded, i2c, rs232, interface, controller

anyone have reccomendations for an IC that can be used to access a device with an RS-232 interface from an I2C bus?

Id rather have something that doesnt need programming as I already have a uC master onthe bus that is taking up a good percentage of my time as the main development area of the project.
Howevre I need to get from I2C to SSH and lantronix have what is effectively a RS232 to linux webserver component, about one of the only embedded components that will allow SSH that I have been able to find.

Only prblem is its interface is RS232, which I dont have currently available...

http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport-pro.html

Ta

Comment: Are you working with true RS-232 (+/- 10 V) or a logic-level UART?

Comment: logic level UART

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NXP make a range of I2C to UART bridge chips, http://ics.nxp.com/products/bridges/i2c.spi.slave.uart.irda.gpio/

http://ics.nxp.com/products/bridges/i2c.spi.slave.uart.irda.gpio/images/use.remote.gif

Have a look at the [SC16IS740](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for will be tricky. As Joby replied, going from UART to I2C is not hard. However going from I2C to UART is harder. This is mainly because UART is full duplex, and the 'slave' can send a response any time it wishes. But you, coming from a I2C, means that the bridge chip will have to have an internal buffer, to store data received from UART and then serve it to I2C master when you are ready. There is nothing impossible about this, but there are many variables, like how big the buffer should be, how to deal with overflow etc. that are specific to your application. And this usually requires firmware I am afraid.

Please, do check the suggestion above. But please note that the diagram indicated conversion not in the direction you asked.

Comment: Be aware that the "suggestion above" might move below depending on up-votes and other answers submitted.

Comment: Right, it's better to link to each answer's anchor using the 'link' button: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2SQjV.png.  This will always take you to Joby's current answer, regardless of whether he posts a second answer, whether the votes swing this around somewhere, whether a flood of answers comes in and these are moved to separate pages, etc.

Comment: Also, I've edited [Joby's answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30141) to convert in the other direction per your answer and the comments.